# MS SQL restore databse from python through windows commands

Tags: python, sql-server, database

I want to restore DB on MS SQL Server 2008 using python3.2/tkinter. Do I have any commands that would rename(if it exists already) DB and then restore it. How can I do it from python only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `_mssql` from `pymssql`.

```
import _mssql

conn = _mssql.connect(server='', user='', password='', database='')
conn.execute_non_query("IF EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'mydb') BEGIN ALTER DATABASE mydb MODIFY NAME = mydb_old END")
conn.execute_non_query("RESTORE DATABASE mydb FROM DISK='C:\mydb.bak'")
```

Quick, MSSQL-y and easy.

Comment: Actually, I just have pythone3.2 only. Its is on office server, They won't let me install extra modules etc. 
I guess there are windows commands for SQL Server that would let you back-up and restore DB from command prompt?

Comment: @AashiqHussain There is `sqlcmd` utility, which you can pass commands to I guess: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-ms-sql-list-tables-and-database/

Comment: I want to execute commands without entering user name and password. I would like to execute it as current logged on user. How to that stuff from a python script.
Thanks for the response.

Comment: @AashiqHussain Just `sqlcmd -S <server>`. First result on google.